# How to create new table from Azure data factory in Azure SQL when copy succeeded or fail

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am doing copy activity in Azure data factory. I am copying csv file to azure sql db. I already setup all the things from linker service to data set. What I want is if copy activity succeeded or fail then I want to insert TableName, No. of rows copied and status (succeeded, fail) into Another table in Azure SQL. How can it be done.

Comment: Are you copying into a existing table ? if yes then you would know the TableName and can be hardcoded, rest Status and number of rows can be taken dynamically

Comment: Yes, I have created two table in Azure SQL database. One is for copying data from blob storage csv to SQL DB and other is for inserting TableName, No. of rows copied and status. How should I insert data from Data factory to second table? Which activity should I use for the same.

Comment: all can be achived, please check my answer 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **parameterized** **StoredProcedure Activity**. You can then assign the values to parameter dynamically in pipeline.

### Example:

Table to store copy details.

```
Create table [dbo].[CopyDetails](
TableName nvarchar(max),
NoOfRows int,
CopyStatus nvarchar(max)
)
```

Stored Procedure in same database as being copied

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recordDetails @TableName nvarchar(max), @NoOfRows int, @CopyStatus nvarchar(max)
AS
Insert into [dbo].[CopyDetails] 
VALUES
(@TableName, @NoOfRows, @CopyStatus)
GO
```

Create Variables accordingly in Pipeline

[image]

Sample working pipeline

[image]

[image]

**Set variableRowsCopied**

```
@string(activity('Copy data1').output.rowsCopied)
```

**Set variableStatus**

```
@activity('Copy data1').output.executionDetails[0].status
```

**Set StoredProcedure Activity**

Use variable to set dynamic values to Stored procedure parameters

[image]

### After successfully executing

[image]

[image]

Comment: What should the value of tableName variable?

Comment: you can hard code it as default value in variable since you mentioned you know the table into which it is being copied

Comment: you can see the in the first screenshot in my answer as `csvCopied`

Comment: And what should be procedure in case I don't know tableName?

Comment: I presume you will be mentioning that in the sink dataset in any way to actually execute the copy right, so how are you going to mention in the sink dataset ? if dynamically .. a parameter perhaps, so you can assign the parameter value to variable in that case.

Comment: Thanks, helped me lot. Please accept my request on linkedin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240948/discussion-between-akhil-omar-and-karthikbhyresh-mt).